# Business objects (DTO) in Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, oop, spring-data-jpa

By default Spring Data Repositories process database Entities. Please, suggest the standard approach of getting same functionality with Spring Data framework, which allows you operating on your Business Domain Objects (DTO) instead of Entities, and encapsulates all DTO to/from Entity mappings.
My current obvious options are:

1. Additional "proxy-wrapper" where all methods have same names as in Spring Repository but accept and return DTO types and encapsulate conversions(mappings).
2. Some clever implementation of previous option using AOP with less boilerplate code.

Both options seem pretty awkward to me for such a standard task. So, I assume I am jut missing something here.

Comment: What's the reason you think it's a good idea to copy entities into DTOs all the time? DTOs are usually used on out- or inbound gateways to potentially map domain concepts to concepts expected by the external party. DTO is Data Transfer Object by the way, not Business Domain Object. I haven't heard of the latter. Entities *are* domain objects.

Comment: Any description of proper repository pattern implementation holds answers to all your questions. It's a shame, that Spring's Repository doesn't implement Repository Pattern properly.

Comment: @GaryR - Care to elaborate?